# NetHack client for iPhone

Tags: ios, nethack

Is there a NetHack client for the iPhone? I have tried telnetting to "nethack.alt.org", but it's vey awkward.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. [Here is one on the app store](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/nethack/id334281275?mt=8#). I cannot vouch for this app's quality, however, having never used/played it.

Comment: It's pretty good.  Strange touch interface.  You get used to it after a while.

Comment: There are two iPhone clients that I've found. The linked one is superior by far. It allows you to use a number of different graphics sets, and incorporates a gesture system that works very well once you know a few of the more common commands.